# How to do transition on background image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, css-transitions

how can i create a menu transition like [this site](http://hostiran.net/home). in css3 i am using transition property but the problem is it is not working in firefox. in fact transition on background image property does not work in firefox. i searched on web to find a way. most of people says that using two div on each other and fade out top div and fade in bottom div but i don't like this method. in [this site](http://hostiran.net/home), as you see in main menu it does't use this method. my question is what method does [this site](http://hostiran.net/home) use. do they using special kind of jquery plugin or not.
is there any jquery plugin to do background transition?

Comment: Do you mean the gradient from light grey to dark grey?

Comment: i exactly mean this[picture](http://info.qweb.ir/Capture.PNG). i want to make a menu trnsition just like [this site](http://hostiran.net/home) but the problem is that in firefox background transition does not work!

Comment: is there any jquery solution. what solution mentioned site use>?

Answer (score 1):

These nav icons have been generated using Twitter [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) icon fonts directory.

See [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons) for more details.
For the transition, simple color transition will work here.